# array swapping for car game

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I am trying to design a program to swap the value 0 in an array with the preceding element if it is not a 0.

For  instance, if the array is `1 1 0 1 1 1` then the program  will keep swapping until it becomes `0 1 1 1 1 1`

But when I run this `IndexOutOfBoundException` occurs. I even tried changing the for loop to:

```
for(int i = 1; i < newLane.length; i++)
```

that solved the out of bounds issue, but made it function incorrectly.

The below is my code:

```
public static int[] down(int[] lane) {   
    int lan = lane.length; // length of array
    int[]newLane = new int[lan];  // creates new 1d matrix

    for(int i = 1; i < newLane.length; i++) {  
        if(newLane[i-1] != 0 && newLane[i] == 0 ){ // getting out of bounds error
            int tmp = newLane[i - 1];
            newLane[i - 1] = newLane[i];
            newLane[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return newLane;
}
```

Comment: in the if-statement you say `newLane[i-1]` if you start from 1, you'll be all right, but skip the first element (as you do now). If you start from 0 you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. My suggestion is to start from 1 and do the first time outside (before) the loop.

Comment: what is `function incorrectly` btw?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply sort your array :

```
public static int[] down(int[] lane){       
    int lan = lane.length; // length of array
    int[]newLane = Arrays.copyOf(lane,lan)  // creates new 1d matrix
    Arrays.sort(newLane);
    return newLane;
}
```

Comment: No, he doesn't want to get the 0 at the front, he wants it to swap with the previous entry in the array, and only if it's predecessor isn't a 0.

Comment: But  `swap with the previous entry in the array, and only if it's predecessor isn't a 0`  means `get all the 0 at the front`.

Comment: Yes, but not in one method call. It was a car game before Brian Webster edited, remember? So this method is called `down`, I suppose that's short for `go down`. Most games just don't say `You want from A to B? Luckily, we just do an array sort so you don't have to do all difficult things to come there, but just wait as few ms.`

Answer (score 0):

You are nowhere using the elements of array `Lane`. Currently `newLane` is an empty array. I have assigned value of `Lane` to `newLane`

Change your function to below

```
public static int[] down(int[] lane){   

    int lan = lane.length; // length of array
    int[]newLane = new int[lan];  // creates new 1d matrix
    newLane = lane;

     for(int i = 1; i < newLane.length; i++) {  

         if(newLane[i-1] != 0 && newLane[i] == 0 ){ // getting out of bounds error
            int tmp = newLane[i - 1];
            newLane[i - 1] = newLane[i];
            newLane[i] = tmp;
            }



    }

         if(newLane[0]!=0 && newLane[1]==0)
         {
             int tmp = newLane[0];
                newLane[0] = newLane[1];
                newLane[1] = tmp;
         }
     return newLane;
    }
```

**Update**
Just after the for loop, check whether the 0th element is non-zero. If yes, then swap it with first.

```
if(newLane[0]!=0 && newLane[1]==0)
         {
             int tmp = newLane[0];
                newLane[0] = newLane[1];
                newLane[1] = tmp;
         }
```

Comment: I think he left the initialization of newLane away to shorten thr code. He explicitly stated that it `functions incorrectly` since he changed the for-loop.

Comment: Well I assumed he didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment already says: you're close.
Just add

```
if(newLane[0] == 0) newLane[0] == 1;
```

Before the for-loop.

Comment: He is not using the passed array `Lane`. How do you think this will work ?

Comment: You know my assumptions. I think he is checking the right array, but left the initialization away while shortening his code, but I already asked what he means with `functions incorrectly`. @ShashankKadne

Answer (score -1):

I will try this

```
 public static int[]  swapping(int[] lane) 
  {   
int[] result = new int[lane.length];  

 for(int i = 0; i < result .length; i++) {  
      if ( result[i]==0) 
      {
        if( i==0)
           {
           }
         else
            {
       temp = result[i] ; 
       result[i]  = result [i-1] ; 
       result [i-1] = temp ; 
             }
     else
      {
       }
 return result ;
}
```

Comment: This will always return an array of 0's.